# How can I install software without an internet connection?

Tags: installation, offline

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. If I don't have an internet connection, how can I manually install the audio plugins, some drivers and stuff like that? Is there any offline process where I can have all my software in some folder and use them whenever I format the system?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install drivers or audio plugins or stuff like that, in most cases all of it cames with linux kernel. To offline installation of some software you will need another machine with same Ubuntu version. If you mean applications settings, than it stored in your home folder. If you made a separate partition for it your settings should be saved when you *correct* reinstall system.

Comment: but i dint get the plugins preinstalled,when i tried to play a mp3,the rhythmbox said there are some plugins missing.and with my ubuntu 12,there is no wine preinstalled

Comment: but i dint get the plugins preinstalled,when i tried to play a mp3,the rhythmbox said there are some plugins missing.and with my ubuntu 12,there is no wine preinstalled

Comment: "in most cases all of it cames with linux kernel" is not correct for Ubuntu because certain software cannot be included in the iso for legal reasons. These, restricted extras, need to be installed separately.

Comment: @vasa1 can i do that if i dont have an internet connection? i mean can i get all those missing plugins,the wine and similar stuff for once,save it in a pen drive or something and use it whenever i format the system? is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you will need another machine with same Ubuntu version and internet connection. http://askubuntu.com/q/974/22548